# Sorting a finite number of elements where each element takes 1 bit of memory in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create a type set, that holds like so

```c
typedef struct set
{
    char *blocks;
    char *numbers;
    char blockNum;
};
```

then in order to create it I do

```c
void createSet(set *newSet)
{
    newSet->blockNum = 1;
    newSet->blocks = calloc(newSet->blockNum, BYTE_SIZE);
}
```

I can initially get numbers from [0,127], with no duplicates
so in order to do that, I want to change the nth bit into 1, and then when I want to read the set, I look at the memory that `set.blocks` take, and check the position of each bit inside it, if a bit is equal to 1, then the number that is equal to the position of that bit is in the set.
here's the code for adding an item

```c
void addItem(set *set, unsigned int item)
{
    int blocksToAdd = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int r = (item / BYTE_SIZE);
    int rem=item % BYTE_SIZE;
    if (r > set->blockNum)
    {
        if(r!=0) {
            blocksToAdd = r - (set->blockNum);
        }
        set->blocks = realloc(set->blocks, (set->blockNum + blocksToAdd)*BYTE_SIZE);
    }
    *(set->blocks+r)  = (1 << rem);
}
```

also, I increase the memory of blocks, by adding the amount of bytes needed to get the nth amount of bits,
so far it kinda works, but when the selected number to add is 7, I get that `*blocks: -128` when it supposed to be 128, I guess it happen cause the then `*blocks = 1000 0000`.

So, I tried working around it but I couldn't get it to work, and I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

the goal was to store numbers from [0,127] with no duplicates, in a way that each element(number) takes 1 bit of memory.

```c
    int num =*(set->blocks+r);
    if(num<0) {
        set->blocks = (char *)realloc(set->blocks, (set->blockNum + 1)*BYTE_SIZE);
        num*=-1;
        *(set->blocks+r)  = num;
    }
```

Tried doing this to get around it, but it wouldn't work

**edit**

I managed to fix the issue, by changing blocks from char* to unsigned char*, also allocated 16 bytes from the start since calling relloc to increase the size every time isn't efficient, so I would instead check if I can decrease the memory allocated for set after adding all the items

Comment: The signed-ness of chars is (I believe) undefined in C. #include <stdint.h> and use uint8_t for this type of thing.

Comment: yeah figured that out eventually, also had other bits of code that were a mess, but I got it working